# EF Core and ASP.net MVC Query too large

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm trying to determine the best way to either change my data model or linq query to reduce redudant SQL columns being queried.

i have a customer model , item model, and customerItem join entity.

i need the customer name and item name from customer model and item model respectively.

if i view the SQL with SQL profiler, its Select * from all 3 tables.

How I can select * from customerITem ONLY include customer.customerName,Item.ItemName ?

var aMRSContext = _context.CustomerItems.Include(c => c.Customer).Include(c => c.Item);

Comment: select customer.customerName,Item.ItemName from customerITem

Comment: Use `.Select()` to project just the columns you need from the object graph. You do not need to use `.Include()` in this case as EF will compose a query to retrieve just the columns you need.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ViewModel to display the data:

```
public class CustomerItemVM
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
var aMRSContext = _db.CustomerItems
            .Select(c=>new CustomerItemVM { 
                CustomerName=c.Customer.CustomerName,
                ItemName=c.Item.ItemName
            })
            .ToList();
```